# Thymeleaf: Get href without application context path

Tags: thymeleaf

How to get URL without context path?
I am using spring boot 1.5.18.RELEASE and Thymeleaf

I tried this two possibilities.

```
<a th:href="@{${website}}" target="_blank"> Click here </a>

<a th:href="${website}" target="_blank"> Click here </a>
```

For example if the ${website} has the value www.example.com I get this result:

http://localhost:8081/MyApp/www.example.com
but I would like to get only this www.example.com  without context Path.

Comment: I think you need to remove base context path and send

Comment: check this :https://medium.com/@trevormydata/week-5-thymeleaf-with-spring-mvc-rapid-introduction-to-the-essentials-799f1fba8c07

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it so:

```
<th:block th:with="link=${website}">
         <a th:href="@{//{link}(link=${link})}" target="_blank">&gt; Click here</a>
</th:block>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are linking to an external site, you should have `http://` or `https://` as part of the link -- `https://www.example.com` rather than just `www.example.com`.  once you've added that, either of the two solutions in your initial post will work.

```
<a th:href="@{${website}}" target="_blank">Click here</a>
<a th:href="${website}" target="_blank">Click here</a>
```

`//` as you've indicated will work as well, but it's a bit silly.  That just means that if your site is `https://` it the link will be `https://` (and vice versa for `http://`).

If you don't want to add `https://` to your link, I would recommend something like this:

```
<a th:href="|https://${website}|" target="_blank">&gt; Click here</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use dynamically, it works to me

```
<img th:src="${#httpServletRequest.scheme}+'://'+${#httpServletRequest.serverName}+':'+${#httpServletRequest.serverPort}+@{/user/display/${user.id}}" />
```